# How would i make a function that will take user input and match it to a array and output the one that matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, input, output

```
function getItemFromSafe(password) {
    const itemsMap = {
      '10-A-w-4-878': 'Magic Wand',
      '16-R-a-9-1497': 'The one ring to rule them all',
      '5-N-3-441': 'Corgi',
      '9-Y-d-2-643': 'Apples and Pears',
      '7-H-673': 'Oscar nomination',
      '12-D-l-4-860': 'Chocolate Brownie'
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (itemsMap[password]) {
        resolve(itemsMap[password])
      } else {
        reject('Unauthorised access to safe')    
      }
    })
  }
```

Then a function i want to write is

```
async function unlockSafe(customerName) {
  /** 
   * WRITE YOUR CODE IN HERE 
   **/
};
```

so i want to write a function that will generate the correct password based on the customers name who is trying to access the safe.

Like if you entered Magic Wand the password for that will come out and if there are any errors to display and error

Comment: why are you using a Promise? your function just needs to `return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(itemsMap).map(([a,b])=>[b,a]))[customerName];`

Comment: How would I do it with the promise, so I would use the second function and pass the customer name into that and it would return the password if it matches?

Comment: `itemsMap` is an object, not an array.

Comment: You should make `itemsMap` a global variable so it can be accessed by both functions. `getItemFromSafe()` can only look up the name from a password, it can't go the other way.

Comment: `How would I do it with the promise` - wrap it in a Promise constructor like you did the first completely synchronous code